# Sql error "Syntax error or access violation: 1064"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, drush

getting (syntax error or access violation 1064) dont know what is the problem. why i am getting this error? I think problen in my syntax with **DATE**

here is the screen with error:
[image]

My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT ds.id
FROM documents ds
INNER JOIN institutions_if ib on ds.to_inst_id = ib.id
INNER JOIN documents_log dl on ds.id = dl.doc_id
WHERE
  ds.to_inst_id in :insts
  AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(dl.timestamp)) = '2014-12-31'   //   <======== ERROR HERE!!!!!
  AND ds.status in ('sent','received','accepted','archived')
  AND ds.template_id = :template1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM documents dr
        WHERE
            dr.reply_to = ds.id
            and dr.template_id = :template2
            and dr.status in ('sent','received','accepted','archived')
            and dr.to_inst_id in :insts
        );";

  $result = db_query($sql, array(
    ':insts' => institution_children_plan('[237, 279, 373]'),
    ':template1' => DocumentTemplate::get_template_by_handler('disp_suspend_operat_cont'),
    ':template2' => DocumentTemplate::get_template_by_handler('comun_anul_disp_susp_oper')
  ));
```

Comment: What happens if you remove that row?

Comment: What is this about Drush?

Comment: Hmm, error now in line "AND ds.status in ('sent','received','accepted','archived')"
So I think problem in line "ds.to_inst_id in :insts", you see something wrong?

Comment: If you run into a problem like this, simply remove things until the problem is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed  the () around the first  IN content

```
WHERE   ds.to_inst_id in (:insts)
```

so you have an error on the next AND

Comment: as `:insts` will be bound as a string, have you tried this?

Comment: thk for you answer. But now I have new error :D

Comment: You can't use a param for a string and use as  an array  .. for this you need  dinamic sql  ..(  string with sql concatenaed ..  but check for content for avoid  sql injection)

Comment: Or you could use several  OR condition instead of an IN clause  ..